# Using Maven to download dependencies without mavenising my project

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am looking at using [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/index.html), which seems to mainly be [distributed/managed using Maven](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/downloads.html). I am not a Maven user (I've always got away with using Ant), and don't feel I should need to mavenise my project purely in order to be able to use Spring Batch.

Are there any tools or Maven commands that I can use to download the various dependencies? There are no recent releases of Spring Batch that are marked "with dependencies".

Should I just create a Maven project that uses Spring Batch and then download the dependencies like that and then extract the jars that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the maven ant tools or ivy to connect an ant built to the maven dependency/repository system.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use.  If you put this is in pom.xml, you can run

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

from a command line and you'll end up with jars in your libs directory.

```
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GuavaExtensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>guavaExtensions</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.chuusai</groupId>
      <artifactId>shapeless_2.10.0-M3</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>scala-actors</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.10.0-M4</artifactId>
      <version>1.9-2.10.0-M4-B2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>scala-actors</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-cli</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>./libs</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```